# After calling itself, Python function won't return correctly. Why?

Tags: python, function, return

I'm making a text adventure game. After the title has printed, the function below prompts the player to begin the game by pressing "y". If they enter "y", the function returns "opening". If not, the function advises them to mind their inputs and calls itself to start over.

The function returns correctly if the player hits "y" the first time. The problem I'm having is that if the player enters the wrong input, subsequent attempts to enter "y" do not return correctly. They skip to the bottom of the function and return my error message "this is wrong".

How can I get the function to return correctly after calling itself?

```
def prompt():

    print "Hit 'Y' to begin."

    action = raw_input("> ").lower()

    if action == "y":
        return "opening"

    else:
        print "For this game to work, you're going to have to get"
        print "the hang of hitting the right key."
        print "Let's try that again."
        prompt()

    return "this is wrong"

ret = prompt()
print ret
```

Comment: you need to `return prompt()`

Comment: Problem solved, thanks. Can you explain why it's necessary to return prompt() versus calling it directly?

Comment: You really also should read [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](//stackoverflow.com/q/23294658), which shows you how to do this properly, without recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are just calling the function again but not returning the value, it should be

```
    print "Let's try that again."
    return prompt()
```

However, you shouldn't be doing this recursively at all...

```
def prompt():

    print "Hit 'Y' to begin."

    action = raw_input("> ").lower()

    while action != "y":
        print "For this game to work, you're going to have to get"
        print "the hang of hitting the right key."
        print "Let's try that again."
        action = raw_input("> ").lower()

    return "opening"
ret = prompt()
print ret
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and thanks doubly for the improvement.

Answer (score 0):

use `return prompt()` inside function